# ffmpeg command with action subprocess

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I want to run this command in a python script

```
cmd = 'ffmpeg -ss ' + start_time + ' -i remove_takeoff.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]trim=0,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[b];[b][0]overlay=shortest=1" -shortest -c:a trimmed_takeoff.mp4'
```

I'm using the following code snippet

```
import subprocess
import shlex

cmd = # the command
suprocess.call(shlex.split(cmd))
```

I'm getting the following error

```
Trailing options were found on the commandline.
```

The above error occurring because the shlex.split command is converting the double quotes of the part into single quote. How to avoid this from happening. Can anyone suggest me a solutions for this problem.

Check the full error trace below.

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC) 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/vkv/anaconda3 
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Trailing options were found on the commandline.
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'remove_takeoff.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.67.100
  Duration: 00:00:14.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15883 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 15881 kb/s, 20 fps, 20 tbr, 10240 tbn, 40 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
Filter overlay has an unconnected output
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/jeykKD37 check this link for error trace, due SO limitations I can't post it here.

Comment: Please use the "edit" link to update your question rather than leave a comment...

Comment: There is also another message: "Filter overlay has an unconnected output".

Comment: As I have mentioned my error trace 900 + characters over SO limit.

Comment: The second error will be solved if the first error is solved. So I have mentioned only the first error.

Comment: I have achieved what I wanted  by using `moviepy` module for python. I have abandoned this approach. But it would be nice if someone found a solution to this.